# 301 Redirect on a server and an ASP page

Tags: 301-redirect, linux, asp

This question may seem a bit "childish" but I was wondering what a browser would read first if a 301 redirect is implemented.

So if a 301 is implemented on an ASP page (script) would the browser read that first or would a 301 on the server-end (Linux server) load first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a server side language, no matter what else you put on the page, the code will execute before it is ever rendered in the browser.

So, no, the browser will never see the rest of the page.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help.